# Получить список моделей в django

Tags: python, django, model

Как получить список всех моделей в Django, импортируя их через:
from .models import *

Т.е. если добавится новая модель, не нужно было бы её импортировать отдельно.
Чтобы она добавилась в отдельный список, откуда её потом можно взять по какому-либо условию.

Comment: смотрите оф. доки на `AppConfig.get_models`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно найти все подклассы класса `django.db.models.Model`:

```py
from django.db.models import Model
from . import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

all_models = []
for e in dir(models):
    if isinstance(getattr(models, e), ModelBase) and issubclass(getattr(models, e), Model):
        all_models.append(getattr(models, e))
```

или покороче

```py
from django.db.models import Model
from . import models

all_models = list(filter(dir(models), lambda e: issubclass(getattr(models, e), Model)))
```

Comment: Я добавил проверку на тип, т.к. выскакивала ошибка issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так `from . import models`, и если нужно обратиться к модели User то можно прописать `models.User`

Если нужно импортировать модели из разных файлов то можно сделать это добавив `__init__.py` в пакет где лежат файлы модели.

Например есть такая иерархия:

```
service.py
/models
 - __init__.py
 - users.py
 - books.py
```

Тогда в `__init__.py` код будет таким:

```
from . users import *
from . books import *
```

И теперь если нужно будет импортировать пакет, например сделаем это в файле `service.py`

```
from . import models

models.User # Эта модель изначально была в файле models.users.User
```

Готово, теперь при добавлении новых моделей в файлах, не нужно будет прописывать новые импорты.